# Get newest SQL dump file

Tags: bash

I have following date and time saved as filenames:

```
/app/sql/20190101_2000.sql
        /20190115_1423.sql
        /20190222_1255.sql
        / etc...
```

Now I want to make a script to get me the newest file, based on its name. I can't go for the last edit or creation date, because sometimes a bunch of those files are imported and get the datetime from its import, not its creation.

The format is, as you can see `YYYYMMDD_hhmm.sql`

What I got so far (sorry, I am no expert in bash)

```
newestfile="000000000000"

for file in *.sql ; do
    filedate="${file%.sql}" # remove the '.sql'
    filedate="${filedate//_}" # remove the underscore, so I can compare

    if [[ "$filedate" -gt "$newestfile" ]] ; then
        newestfile="$filedate"
    fi
done

echo "highest file found: $newestfile"
```

The problem is, I cannot go further. I now want to import that "newest" file into mysql, but I cannot get the underscore back where it was. If I don't remove the underscore in the first place, I cannot compare with `-gt`.

My code would look like in the continuing kinda like this:

```
mysql -uuser -p1234 my_database < $newestfile
```

to import the sql dump.

Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your files and get the first one

```
newestfile=$(ls /app/sql/$.sql | sort -r | head -n 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
ls -R *.sql | sort | tail -1
```

`ls -R` does an `ls` inside subdirectories.
`sort` does a sorting.
`tail -1` takes the last one. As the result is sorted, the one with the highest date is shown.